# Anchor confusion with winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

So this is going to be hard to descirbe without pictures (can't upload anything at work), but I have a form with 2 groupboxes and 2 buttons laid out like this:

```
group    button    group
box      button    box
```

What crazy combinations of anchors do I need to do make it to where the right edge of the left box, the buttons and the left edge of the right box stay absolute and everything else autosizes?  I tried top, bottom, left on left box and top, bottom, right on right box but that just gets me a strange effect where the space in between the buttons and the boxes grows.

Sorry for the weak description, again, hard to do with no pics.  If you have any questions throw them in the comment and Ill do my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doable with `Control.Anchor`.  Instead, you can try with a `TableLayoutPanel`:

```
TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel()
                       {
                           RowCount = 2,
                           ColumnCount = 3,
                           ColumnStyles = {
                               new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize),
                               new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, buttonWidth),
                               new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize)
                           }
                       };

tlp.Controls.Add(groupBox1, 0, 0);
tlp.Controls.Add(button1, 1, 0);
tlp.Controls.Add(button2, 1, 1);
tlp.Controls.Add(groupBox2, 2, 0);

tlp.SetRowSpan(groupBox1, 2);
tlp.SetRowSpan(groupBox2, 2);
```

You might need to use `ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50)` instead of autosize, I'm not certain on the behaviour.

Comment: I added this code to the constructor of the form in question and now nothing shows when it loads... tried `tlp.Visable = true` but that wasn't it, any thoughts?

Comment: Got it to work, thanks! Ended up having to set column 1 and 3 to percent, 50 and column 2 to autoSize (put both buttons in a panel so I wouldn't need 2 rows for the layout panel).

Comment: Isn't it easier to do this via the visual editor? That way you wouldn't have to compile it every time you change something.

Comment: @ThaMe90 I did end up doing it in the editor, but I used the values he gave in the code so close enough to accept the answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Anchor everything Top and Left. Anchor ony the right box to Right and Bottom.

Comment: Tried that, but wasnt the effect I was going for... when I autosize that form to the right I end up with<br>
`groupbox....button.............................groupbox`<br>
trying to get everything to stay relative to the center

Comment: If you un-anchor everything, sizes will stay fixed and everything will be center-aligned. Is that the desired effect?

Comment: No I do want the boxes to resize when the window is resized, otherwise you just get empty space all around it... if I went about it that way I'd just make the form a fixed size but I don't want to do that.

Comment: So you want the buttons to be center-aligned at constant size, with the boxes to expand on left and right?

Comment: Correct, along with the right edge of the left group box and the left edge of the right group box maintaining their distance from the center-aligned and constant size buttons if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just wrap all three columns (groupbox, button, groupbox) in a grid, with 3 columns, of which column 1 and 3 have a fixed width, and the middle one have a variable width?

I know this works with XAML windows. Don't know for sure with WinForms though.

Comment: Hmm so like 2 split containers arranged to make 3 columns?

Comment: Mainly you just wrap your controls in a container control to which you can set the desired widths on different columns. Like a table.

Comment: The comment formatting destroyed your pic but I think I get it... only question is I don't really know what grid control you're talking about, is that WPF? I'm in Winforms.

Comment: Yes, Grid is a component from WPF. The closest alternative I could find for WinForms is a TableLayoutPanel. It lets you add and remove (and resize) rows and columns. I think that is your easiest solution.